# Google Script call another function to return a value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting to grips with beginner methods of GScript now but so far have only used one function. Could someone show me how to 'call' another function to check for something and then return a TRUE or FALSE. Here is my attempt (it will eventually check a lot of things but I'm just checking one thing to start..)

```
Function callAnotherFunctionAndGetResult () {
MyResult = call(CheckTrueFalse)
if(MyResult = True then.. do something)
};

function CheckTrueFalse() {
if(3 > 2) { 
CheckTrueFalse = TRUE
Else
CheckTrueFalse = FALSE
};
```

So basically I just want to get the other function to check something (in this case is 3 bigger than 2?) if it is then return TRUE. From this I should have the knowledge to modify for the real purpose. I'm used to Visual Basic so I've written it more how that would look - I know that won't work. Could someone help me convert so will work with Google Script please?

Comment: google apps script is basically javascript, it may be helpful to look into [javascript docs on variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables) or this [Codecademy course on javascript](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript)

Answer (score 2):

A function with a return statement is what you're looking for. Assuming you need the called function to take some input from the main function:

```
function mainFunction() {
    //...
    var that = "some variable found above";
    //call other function with input and store result
    var result = otherFunction(that); 
    if (result) {
        //if result is true, do stuff
    }
    else {
        //if result is false, do other stuff
    }
}

function otherFunction(that) {
    var this = "Something"; //check variable
    return (this == that); 
    //(this == that) can be any conditional that evaluates to either true or false,
    //The result then gets returned to the first function
}
```

You could also skip assigning the result variable and just check the returned condition directly, i.e.:

```
if (otherFunction(that)) {
    //do stuff
}
else {do other stuff}
```

Let me know if you need me to clarify any of the syntax or if you have any more questions.

Comment: What if you have this, for some reason, it doesn't "always" work....

```function doGet(e) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<FILE ID HERE>/edit#gid=0");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
  
  addUser(e,sheet);
}

function addUser(e,sheet) {
  var id = e.parameter.id ; 
  var name = e.parameter.name ;

  sheet.appendRow([id,name]);
}```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic sample that might help you:

```
function petType(myPet){
    return myPet;
}

function mainFunctoin(){

  var newPet = petType("dog");

  if(newPet === "dog"){
     Logger.log("true");
  }else{
     Logger.log("false");
  }

}
```

**Execute mainFunction().**

If you set `petType` to "cat", it will return false; but, if you set it to "dog", it will return true.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Sorry for late reply, only just had chance to look at this again. My code is working great now.